# Please explain these lines in the jQuery-ui project - has to do with adding "sub-plugins"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

Lines 10 - 16 of [jquery.effects.core.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/e3156ea28617e6cc30a3389ee8d3f30514b9d894/ui/jquery.effects.core.js):

```
;jQuery.effects || (function($, undefined) {

    var backCompat = $.uiBackCompat !== false; // Irrelevant

    $.effects = {
        effect: {}
    };

})(jQuery); // At end of file
```

As I understand it, this adds an `effects` "namespace", but only if it doesn't already exist.

Can someone explain to me:

1. What is the initial semi-colon for?
2. What is the purpose of the `undefined` parameter? Is the meaning of `undefined` overridden in some way?
3. What's the difference between adding a function directly to the `jQuery` object, and adding one to `jQuery.fn` as recommended in the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)?
4. Finally, if I wanted to create a bunch of jQuery plugins that would only be used by my own team, would it make sense to lump them all under a company namespace using something like the code above?

**Edit:** I realize now jQuery.effects is probably a bad example. I see [jQuery.ui.core.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1856a84d590e1711935b72d1441851f4595f4f7d/ui/jquery.ui.core.js) does it differently:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
    $.ui = $.ui || {};

    // add some stuff to $.ui here

    $.fn.extend({
        // plugins go here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But what is the use of the `ui` object if plugins are added directly to `$.fn` anyway? Could I define my namespace under `$.fn` and add all my plugins to `$.fn.acme`, so that I use them like so: `$('something').acme.doStuff()`?

Is there a best practice for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

- It checks if `jQuery.effects` exists
- If not, it defines a function and calls in the same time
  `(function() { ... } (jquery)`, it passes jQuery object for reasons related to scope and conflict and such.
- The first line in that function is said to be irrelevant, it seems to be checking a presence of a jQuery plugin property
- It defines a placeholder (like namespace or container class) for the effects jQuery plugin property.

So, to your questions:

1 . What is the initial semi-colon for?

I think nothing special. Just ensuring clean statement. This has some edge cases if the last line before this one was a function declaration close.

2 . What is the purpose of the undefined parameter? Is the meaning of undefined overridden in some way?

It just ensures this doesn't happen later. Passes the global object directly. Common pattern I think.

3 . What's the difference between adding a function directly to the jQuery object, and adding one to jQuery.fn as recommended in the jQuery documentation?

It's the way jQuery is structured and general organization issue. The jQuery object is a function and returns an object. The `.fn` handles registering this one to apply on returned jQuery objects (from jQuery select or so), so, that's better so that jQuery actually knows about your added function.

4 . Finally, if I wanted to create a bunch of jQuery plugins that would only be used by my own team, would it make sense to lump them all under a company namespace using something like the code above?

Most people don't do it. Wouldn't recommend it. Maybe a common "small" prefix is enough.